# External HDD......is this beyond repair?

Tags: external-hdd

Problem:WD external hard drive will not mount. I have no access to the driver. It will show up in files under other locations and in disks after about 20 mins of being plugged into the laptop.

Output for dmesg:

```
[ 3611.422557] usb 4-2: New USB device found, 
[ 3611.422571] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[ 3611.422575] usb 4-2: Product: Elements 10B8
[ 3611.422578] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital

[ 3611.456635] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3611.456857] scsi host0: usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[ 3611.456952] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 3611.458659] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 3612.474692] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD  Elements 10B8    1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3612.475089] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 3612.476156] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[ 3613.497891] .......................
[ 3667.243549] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3667.264764] ready
[ 3697.960601] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 3878.057148] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 4058.131137] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 4058.131207] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4058.131216] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 4058.131224] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 4058.131231] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 4058.131234] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 4238.177508] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 4238.177558] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 4418.217232] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[ 4418.217326] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[ 4418.217337] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4418.218144] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[ 4448.234842] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 30s
[ 5922.916734] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 access beyond end of device
[ 5922.916749] I/O error, dev sda, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x1000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5922.916767] EXT4-fs (sda): unable to read superblock
```

Comment: You can try a different cable if you have one at hand, but the disk is probably toast.

Comment: You can also try to put the hdd into an internal drive, with sata power. Perhaps.